# Nginx reverse proxy serving wrong host

Tags: nginx, configuration, reverse-proxy, web-hosting

My Nginx reverse proxy is doing something very odd. One domain in particular is not resolving correctly but instead showing the site of a totally different host. Only **wiki.example.net** is wrong, it redirects to **www.client.co.uk** instead. Everything else is fine.

In 3 separate files in /etc/nginx/sites-available

### default

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
server_name _;

root /var/www/example/;
index index.html index.php;

include /etc/nginx/include/php;
}
```

### wiki.example.net

```
upstream examplewiki  {
  server 10.2.7.18:80;
}


server {
listen 80;
server_name wiki.example.net;

location / {
    proxy_pass  http://examplewiki/;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

### www.client.co.uk

```
upstream client  {
  server 10.2.7.12:80;
}

server {
  server_name .client.co.uk;
  return 301 http://www.client.co.uk$request_uri;
}

server {
  server_name .client.com;
  return 301 http://www.client.co.uk$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 80;
server_name  www.client.co.uk;

location / {
 proxy_pass  http://client/;
 proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
 proxy_redirect off;
 proxy_buffering off;
 proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
 proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 }
}
```

Just for **wiki.example.net** the URL is rewritten to **www.client.co.uk** and the **www.client.co.uk** page shows up. Everything else works as it should. I have other backend VPSs and other similar config files that all work as they should too.

Comment: Update: It's not Nginx after all, it's Firefox on the Ubuntu 14.04 workstation I am using. That solves the Nginx problem but poses an odder question: What could rewrite the URL in Firefox? It doesn't happen in Chromium. It's not the hosts file. I'm baffled.

Comment: Update: I'm going to ask this as a new question.

Comment: are you sure that firefox is not asking https due to some add-on. Also, those 2 servers without listen might be causing some confusion (specially if firefox is requesting the https page)